# How to reinstall Safari on a Mac?

Tags: mac, safari

I am using a MacBook Air 10.14.6, and I am not able to open Safari anymore.

How can I reinstall this app?

A problem report opens with some lengthy debug information in it. Here is maybe the important part:

```
Process:               Safari [2245]
Path:                  /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
Identifier:            Safari
Version:               13.1.2 (14609.3.5.1.5)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Safari [2245]
User ID:               66702218

Date/Time:             2020-10-07 17:25:11.648 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G2022)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     4.2 (17P2551)
Anonymous UUID:        F0A08E7C-38FB-79BF-A87B-5A4AE24494E5


Time Awake Since Boot: 280 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [2245]

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, running initializers
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
Sandbox registration failed: The code signature is not valid: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -67030.)

Application Specific Signatures:
Registration error: The code signature is not valid: The operation couldn’t b

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_secinit.dylib         0x00007fff70e40ac1 _libsecinit_setup_secinitd_client + 1824
1   libsystem_secinit.dylib         0x00007fff70e40340 _libsecinit_initialize_once + 13
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff70bf263d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff70bf3d4b _dispatch_once_callout + 20
4   libsystem_secinit.dylib         0x00007fff70e40331 _libsecinit_initializer + 79
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff6dc249d4 libSystem_initializer + 136
...
...
```

Comment: Safari 14 is available for 10.14.6, if you want to try that. It's available as a Supplemental Update.

Comment: Often the best way to proceed, before one reinstalls the whole OS, is to run the most recent Combo Update for your version of macOS. A quick search should direct you to a download page at apple.com.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that you could do is reinstall macos without removing personal files, or other applications. To do this, restart and hold `⌘ + R` while booting. You should go into recovery mode then click reinstall macos, and follow the on-screen instructions. Should take 10 to 30 minutes.